# How many 5-input LUT functions are mappable to two cascaded 4-input LUTs?

Tags: mapping, permutation, lookup, fpga, combinatorics

The questions can be made more precise:
Out of the 2<sup>2<sup>5</sup></sup> = 0x100000000 different functions realizable in a 5-input LUT, are 0x3c1d3c82 functions realizable with two cascaded 4-input LUTs?

## Background

One of the standard building blocks in FPGAs is the 4-input look-up table. One such table can realize 2<sup>2<sup>4</sup></sup> functions. A standard method to construct an arbitrary 5-input LUT is to use three 4-input LUTS, with two levels of logic, and use the second level LUT as a 2-to-1 multiplexer. An arbitrary function f5(i4,i3,i2,i1,i0) may be represented as ff5(i4,g4(i3,i2,i1,i0),h4(i3,i2,i1,i0)), as illustrated below.

```
       ___                ___          
i3 ---|I3 |           ---|I3 |         
i2 ---|I2 |        i4 ---|I2 |--- ff5  
i1 ---|I1 |------- h4 ---|I1 |         
i0 ---|I0_|   +--- g4 ---|I0_|         
       ___    | 
i3 ---|I3 |   |
i2 ---|I2 |---+
i1 ---|I1 |
i0 ---|I0_|
```

## More compact representation

However, many 5-input functions can be represented by two cascaded 4-input LUTs, gg(hh4(j4,j3,j2,j1),j2,j1,j0) where the j<sub>n</sub>'s is a permutation of i<sub>n</sub> (n from 0 to 4). Graphically, this can be shown as:

```
       lut1
       ___            lut2                       
j4 ---|I3 |           ___             
j3 ---|I2 |----hh----|I3 |           
j2 ---|I1 |    j2 ---|I2 |-- gg
j1 ---|I0_|    j1 ---|I1 |
               j0 ---|I0_|
```

## Result, to be verified

I have written a brute force program to find how many true 5-input functions can be represented by the above construction, my results are:

```
0 input lut...... :        0x2   0.0000% (Constant 0 and Constant 1)
1 input lut...... :        0xa   0.0000% (Buffered signal and inverted signal)
2 input lut...... :       0x64   0.0000%
3 input lut...... :      0x884   0.0001%
4 input lut...... :    0x4ed9a   0.0075%
Chained luts..... : 0x3c1d3c82  23.4821%
Uncovered         : 0xc3ddccf0  76.5103%
Total             :0x100000000 100%
```

5-input functions is a super-set of 4-input functions, I do not count those 5-input functions that can be represented in a single LUT (or no LUT at all, for functions `0x00000000` and `0xffffffff`, and arguably 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xf0f0f0f0, 0xcccccccc, 0xaaaaaaaa).

I wonder if someone else have conducted the same exercise, and obtained the same results?

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, but my answer is that looking at your first 3-LUT example, when implemented using any 'modern' FPGA device (Xilinx Spartan 3, Altera Cyclone V, Lattice ECP2 or newer), the 'multiplexer' does not actually use another LUT, rather there is dedicated multiplexer resource specifically for the purpose of creating wider logic functions.

These multiplexers avoid any routing delay that would be incurred by using a third LUT for the multiplexer, or using a chained LUT as in your second example, so the resulting wide LUT should operate at a higher frequency than the chained-LUT approach. They are essentially 'for free', in that they can usually only be used for logic associated with the neighboring LUTs in the same ALM/Slice.

I would also say that even *if* the chained-LUT approach used less logic resource, I would still favor code that was written plainly while using more LUTs, than code that directly instantiated LUTs in this way, with their associated totally unreadable LUT initialisation values.

Comment: I agree with all your facts. Even more important, chained LUTs put severe constraints on input switch boxes, and clogs up routing. But, as you said, this does not answer my question.